# Am I doing this whole API, client app, Oauth/OpenId Connect thing right?

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, web-deployment, openid-connect

I have some programming experience, but only with PHP and Java enterprise systems. But now I have some ideas about a web app in my new job. Since I am new at this, I would like to share how I have done the whole API in a server, browser app and authentication with Google’s OpenID Connect (I read a lot about Oauth and OpenID Connect, most helpful source was this: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect).

Server: Laravel -  hxxps://coolapp-api.mycompany.com

Client: Angular -  hxxps://coolapp.mycompany.com

### TL;DR version:

1) User goes to hxxps://coolapp.mycompany.com, gets an Angular app login page. Types in their email, clicks “Sign in with Google”;

2) The app sends the email to hxxps://coolapp-api.mycompany.com/api/sign-in. The server redirects the user to  hxxps://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth with all the needed parameters;

3) The user logs in to their Google account, gives my app permission if it’s their first time, and Google redirects them to my server at hxxps://coolapp-api.mycompany.com/sign-in/google/callback. The server checks everything, and if it’s all correct, it creates a JWT token and send a redirect to the client app at hxxps://coolapp.mycompany.com/login/callback?token=JWT-TOKEN

4) The client app gets the token, stores it in local storage, and sends it to the server with every API call

### More detailed version:

1) User goes to hxxps://coolapp.mycompany.com, gets an Angular app login page. Types in their email, clicks “Sign in with Google”;

2) The app sends the email to hxxps://coolapp-api.mycompany.com/api/sign-in. The server creates a state token and stores it in cache, associated with the email received. Then the server creates Google’s oauth URL and sends it to the client in the response body. I tried to do it with a HTTP redirect, but Google’s server was responding with an CORS error. The Angular app reads Google’s url from the response and goes there.

3) The user logs in to their Google account, gives my app permission if it’s their first time, and Google redirects them to my server at hxxps://coolapp-api.mycompany.com/sign-in/google/callback?code=AUTHCODE&otherstuff. The server sends the code it received (and all the other needed parameters) to hxxps://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token. It receives a id_token with that user’s email and basic info. This app is not public, so I don’t want anyone with a Google Account logging in, only the clients whose emails I added to the server database. So now the server checks if the user’s email in the token is in the database. If it’s not, it sends the user a HTTP 401 - Unauthorized. Then the server checks the state token in it’s cache associated with the email received. If it’s equal to the one received with Google’s redirect, then the server creates another JWT token, but now signed by my server. Finally, it sends a HTTP redirect to hxxps://coolapp.mycompany.com/login/callback?token=JWT-TOKEN with the new token.

4) The client app gets the token, stores it in local storage, and sends it to the server with every API call

### Some comments:

- Everything is HTTPS;
- I added the strictest CSP policies I could to my Laravel server and Angular client;
- Currently the app only supports Google’s sign in, while it is in development. Later on I’ll add more.
- I made that my server only checks if the user’s email is in the database after they logged in with google because I like that idea that a non-authorized user should have no information about anything. If I made that check before it, during the first round trip, anyone could type an email and discover if that email has an account in my system;
- On the last step, when my server sends the JWT token to my client app, I tried sending the token within a cookie, but since my API and my client app have different domains, my client app couldn't read the token. Sending it in the url was the only solution I could find. I tried logging in a popular app that uses Oauth and they did it this way too.

So my question is:

Am I doing something wrong, unsecure, weird?

Thank you all very much

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1) Entering an email address every time a user wants to log in is tedious. And it's not needed if the user is already logged in at Google. The user should just click the "Log in with Google" button and get logged in without entering anything. The state parameter can be a random string - not related to the user's email in any way.

2) If you want your backend to process the redirect from Google (using the auth code flow - the backend has the client role in OAuth2 terms), the backend should also initiate a redirect to Google - not by sending data containing the redirect URL. To achieve it, after clicking the "Log in with Google" button, perform a whole page navigation (instead of an XHR request) to `/api/sign-in` and if the backend returns HTTP 302, the browser will correctly redirect to Google.

3) You should perform request validation (the `state` parameter) before getting tokens and checking whether the user exist. 
On error (access denied), you can consider redirecting the user to an error page with error details instead of returning HTTP 401, since the HTTP code will cause a generic error screen to be displayed to the user. If you want to keep using HTTP codes, I think [HTTP 403 Forbidden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403) would be more appropriate.

4) Consider using sessionStorage instead of the localStorage. The sessionStorage gets cleared after closing a browser/tab and it's not shared among tabs. It makes it safer and it allows users to use different identity in different browser tabs.
The tokens your backend issues, is their validity time limited? Is the user required to get a new token after some (short) time period? If not, valid token vales may stay in the localStorage and browser's page history, which can be a security problem.

You can consider using your own OAuth2 auth server (such as [RedHat Keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/)) which would accept Google (and later some other providers) for authentication and it would also issue access tokens accepted by your backend.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helped me a lot.
1) I agree, I’m not a fan of the user having to type the email at the first round trip. The state is random, I don’t use the email input to generate it. The email is used in the key to cache the state. Since everything is stateless, I thought I needed a way to know that the second round trip is made in the same “session” that the first. 
But now that I’m thinking about it, I’m starting to think that it is not necessary to cache the state associated with the email. It doesn’t seem to add anything in terms of CSRF protection. I’ll look more into it.

Comment: 2) I didn’t know that, I’ll try it
3) Good point, makes sense
4) I used localStorage so the user is already logged in when they open their browser after logging in previously. It seems to me that this is the most common behavior in apps. I’ll do more research about it.

Comment: To clarify 1), I was doing this:
First round trip:

$state = generate_random_string();

        
$cache->store( ‘state-’ . $email, $state );

Second round trip:

$cachedState = $cache->get(‘state-’ . $emailFromToken);

 
if ( $cachedState !== $stateFromInput ) {
 // return Unauthorized
}